# Cannot run selenium server using docker

Tags: java, docker, selenium, docker-compose, selenium-grid

I am trying to use this docker compose:

```
 firefox:
    image: myfirefox
    shm_size: '2gb'
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
```

And the container of myfirefox image runs the following commands:

- `java -jar /opt/selenium/selenium-server.jar node --publish-events tcp://"$HUB_HOST":4442 \ --subscribe-events tcp://"$HUB_HOST":4443`
- `java -jar /opt/selenium/selenium-server.jar standalone`

But I got this error:

```
failed to open shm: Permission denied: file /builds/worker/checkouts/gecko/ipc/chromium/src/base/shared_memory_posix.cc, line 246
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 176
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal..
```

I am using **Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086** on Windows 10
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox does not have permission to the /dev/shm directory (failed to open shm:).

The docker image has /dev/shm mounted from the host, thus anything that originally existed for /dev/shm on the base image has been replaced with the host /dev/shm directory. This maybe a change in files, sub-directories and in this case a change to permissions.

It is more than likely that the base image has 777 permissions or specific ownership for /dev/shm, whereas the host /dev/shm directory could have 755 permissions or different ownership to what Firefox requires for it to run on the docker container.

Comment: What do you suggest to fix it?

Comment: First consider why you are mapping the host /dev/shm directory. Is the whole directory required or just a sub-directory. If it is a case of a specific sub-directory within host /dev/shm that does not exist on base image /dev/shm, just mount that sub-directory path to the equivalent base image sub-directory path. Check the permissions and ownership of /dev/shm on the host and on the base image before creating your personal docker image. Then make the appropriate changes, taking into account that you may not want to change permissions on the host /dev/shm directory.

Comment: I am not sure how you are mapping /dev/shm considering your host system is Windows 10. Try to remove volume definition and leave remaining part and run again.

Comment: @AlexeyR. good point about Windows 10, I was assuming they were using WSL. If they are not, then good call to remove volume mapping.

Comment: @djmonki I tried also removing volume mapping but it still does not work

Comment: Can you update your question with the docker build of your myfirefox container, it maybe related to the build